# Program to check if number is odd or even using switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a program that uses a switch statement to check if a number is odd or even.

For some reason I'm not getting anything printed to the console. When I add a default case though, it automatically prints the default (console.log("Invalid input"). Can someone explain why this approach doesn't work?

```
var enteredNumber = 40;
var enteredNumber_div_by2 = enteredNumber/2;

switch(enteredNumber_div_by2) {
    case Number.isInteger(enteredNumber_div_by2) === true:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an even number.");
        break;
    case Number.isInteger(enteredNumber_div_by2) === false:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an odd number.");
        break;
    case enteredNumber_div_by2.isNaN() === true:
        console.log("Invalid input");
        break;
    default: 
        console.log("Invalid input");
}
```

edit: In case anyone else is trying to understand switch statements like I am, I revised my code based on Rocket's answer and it works now. I realize this is not the best way to check if a number is odd or even but I'm doing this solely to understand switch statements. Also, I realized my code doesn't really check if the input is a number so even if you input "hi" it will return "hi is an odd number". Here is my revised switch statement:

```
switch(Number.isInteger(enteredNumber_div_by2) === true) {
    case true:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an even number.");
        break;
    case false:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an odd number.");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Invalid input")
```

edit 2: Nina's answer works the best:

```
switch (enteredNumber % 2) {
    case 0:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an even number.");
        break;
    case 1:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an odd number.");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Invalid input")
}
```

Comment: You don't need a switch statement. You can just use modulo. An even number would be `x % 2 === 0` and an odd number would be `x % 2 === 1`

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! I'm actually just learning how to use switch statement so thats why I'm trying to do it using this approach. I'm just wondering how come it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the remainder and check the value of it.

The [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) takes two values and uses a strict comparison, like `===`.

If you use inside `case` a boolean value, you need to use in the `switch` part another corresounding boolean value.

Even if Javascript offers to use dynamic content in both parts, some people tend to accept only constant values to compare instead of dynamic values.

```js
var enteredNumber = 40;

switch (enteredNumber % 2) {
    case 0:
        console.log(enteredNumber + " is an even number.");
        break;
    case 1:
        console.log(enteredNumber + " is an odd number.");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is is not how `switch` statements work.  A `switch` is used to compare a variable to a list of values.  Such as:

```
let a = 'a';
switch(a) {
    case 'a':
        break;
    case 'b':
        break;
}
```

If you want to check `Number.isInteger(enteredNumber_div_by2)`, then just use an `if`/`else`:

```
if (Number.isInteger(enteredNumber_div_by2)) {
    console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an even number.");
}
else {
    console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an odd number.");
}
```

If for whatever reason you *really* wanted to use a `switch` here, you'd have to do:

```
switch (Number.isInteger(enteredNumber_div_by2)) {
    case true:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an even number.");
        break;
    case false:
        console.log(enteredNumber.toString() + " is an odd number.");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Rocket, thats exactly what I'm looking for. I know there are better ways of doing it based on what I've read on this forum already, but I'm just using this approach to try to understand switch statements better. Thank you!